# magento 1.3.2 3 chaging server from 5.2 to 5.3 php will it effect the website

Tags: magento

i am using magento  1.3.2 3 changing server from 5.2php to 5.3 php will it effect the website

would there be any compatibility issues ?

hosting people:
As discussed on live chat we have migrated your all account from your VPS to new dedicated server.

Also, the OLD server has php version 5.2 ,cPanel is no longer providing support for php 5.2. Your server has php version 5.3. Please check if your all sites are compatible with the php 5.3 and let us know the convenient time period to change the nameserver IPs as bellow.

would there be issues with magento functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

> will it effect the website

Yes.

> would there be any compatibility issues

Magento didn't support PHP 5.3 until version 1.4

> would there be issues with magento functionality ?

Again, yes, but they're too myriad to list.  Upgrading to modern version of Magento won't be a turn key project.  Get a 5.3 server, practice moving your site and fixing all the bugs. Do it again. Keep doing it until you're ready to move your production system.

Comment: If Alan Storm says answer YES to your questions then the answer is 100% perfect. No more suggestions. Follow alan storm suggestions..